# How to store an object containing a list type in Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, list, object

I'm relativly new to C# programming and are trying to figure out the following.

I have a class object called BrandModel which contains 2 properties:

```
BrandModel

public string BrandName { get; set; }
public string BrandImageUrl { get; set; }
```

I also have a class object called CreatedBrandSetModel which contains 2 properties:

```
CreatedBrandSetModel

public string BrandSetName { get; set; }
public List<BrandModel> brands { get; set; }
```

My goal is to systematically store the CreatedBrandSetModel into a SQL database where the CreatedBrandSetModel is associated with the user who created it.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: are you using entity framework? as if you do it'll pretty be pretty simple as `_db.Add(YourObjectComposingAListOfAnotherObject)` where _db will be the object of your `dbcontext`

Comment: you can follow these tutorials series if you want: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx